# Is choice needed to prove that there always exist a deformation in the non-obstructed case?

Tags: representation-theory, axiom-of-choice, group-cohomology, deformation-theory, galois-representations

[If you want a full explanation of my question from scratch, without needing to know anything about deformation theory, look at that : http://lebarde.alwaysdata.net/maths/random/choice.pdf ]

Let $A \rightarrow B$ be, say, a small extension of coefficient rings of residual field $k$. Let $\rho$ be a representation $G \rightarrow GL_n(B)$.

Let's assume for example that $H^2(G,\mathfrak{M}_n(k)) = 0$ for the action $g.M = \bar\rho(g)M\bar\rho(g)^{-1}$. Then it is not that hard to prove that there exists a representation $G \rightarrow GL_n(A)$ that lifts $\rho$.

The proof I know (say, the one in Gouvea) goes this way : first, we consider "set-theoretical liftings" which exist (***assuming choice***), and then we show that the set of these liftings corresponds (by measuring how non-homomorphic it is) to a cohomology class in $H^2(G,\mathfrak{M}_n(k)) \otimes_k \ker(A\rightarrow B)$, which is therefore trivial, which shows that one of these liftings has to be a morphism. This is all beautiful and sweet, but the use of "set-theoretical liftings" and this "hand-made" morphism structure (we take sets, and we build a structure on them by hand, which kinda contradicts the spirit of category theory and modern algebra) bothers me a little. In particular, I have the impression that if I don't assume choice, I can't prove that the cohomology class before exists, and therefore cannot craft a "real" (homomorphic) deformation.

Does anybody know, for example, if this result really requires choice ? Maybe I'm just confused and choice isn't really crucial in the proof above, but I might need some help understanding how this works without choice ^^

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Andreas Blass has a nice paper about cohomology and choice.

Comment: Link to Blass' paper: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8fea/e0297b8e196abea140b1083252c1bada273d.pdf

Comment: I know this paper, but it's really unrelated to the question I asked.

Comment: I wrote a little thing to explain my question from scratch : http://lebarde.alwaysdata.net/maths/random/choice.pdf